# Web API targeting .Net Framework vs .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is **message** pipe line and other constructs same for **Web API** that targets **.Net Core** or **.Net framework**? Can we use **ActionFilters**, **DelagatingHandlers** and other concepts while developing **.Net Core** based Web API?

Comment: if you are familiar with owin, you will find that the architect of the two are similar, but they does not have the same api. the answer should be yes, they have action filters, delegating handlers , but the API are not same exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core, you want use the ASP.NET Core MVC project template. Note, .NET Core MVC and Web API were merged together.

You can read more about the Middleware here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1